# Restrict authentication to only my app

Tags: android, azure, authentication, uwp, azure-mobile-services

At the moment, my app (Android and UWP) uses Azure Easy Tables. To upload/update/delete items in the easy table, a user has to be authenticated. But I only want them to be able to authenticate in the app.
Is there a way to restrict this authentication process to only accept authentication requests coming from my apps?

Comment: what makes you think other apps can access your easy tables? have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, with the authentication method, you have to provide the clientid and key of the Login method to the azure service in the Azure portal. But from the application, you only need the URL to be able to authenticate, after this you only need the name of the table to access/manipulate the items in the table as an 'authenticated' user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no reliable way to authenticate your client. You can use and validate an application key as [documented here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Implementing-Application-Key), but if you're shipping your application with that information, those wouldn't be difficult to extract.

Alternatives are available (different ways to "fingerprint" your app) and while make it a bit more difficult for other clients to use your API, but none of them are foolproof.

Properly authenticating and authorizing the user is sufficient to guarantee that data is only accessible by users with the required permissions, but there's not a way to absolutely guarantee this is done from your client.

Answer (score 0):

As the figure below, did you enable the `App Service Authentication` option of the `Authentication / Authorization` tab of your Mobile App to `ON` and with non-anonymous authenticate way on Azure portal?

[image]

If not, please enable it to protect your Mobile App backend endpoints which include Easy Table, and you need to do the more authentication for calling your Mobile App backend. Please see the details at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service-mobile%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Yes, i did this, authentication is working properly with a google login, but how can i disable authentication from other sources than my own apps?